# Column Filters Not Visible Using Datatable Shiny

Tags: javascript, html, r, shiny, datatables

I have created a data table from the DT package that has over 50 rows. The filter boxes at the top, for that reason are not very large. Their seems to be a lot of unused white space in the filter boxes. Is there anyway to reduce that so I am able to see at least partial of my filters? I will use the iris data set to show you what I would like to see happen vs what I currently have.

```
ui.R
...
 fluidRow(
            column(
                    width = 12,
                    box(width = NULL, status = "info", solidHeader = T, title = "Earnings Scanner",

                     DTOutput("tab"),style = "height:700px; overflow-y: scroll;overflow-x: scroll;font-size:70%;"
                    )
                  )
                )



server.R
...
output$tab = renderDT(
      datatable(
      frame.ea, filter = 'top', options = list(
        pageLength = 10, autoWidth = TRUE), class = 'cell-border stripe', rownames = F)
    )
```

[image]

Using Iris data set you can see what I am trying to achienve
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an issue with the width of your table. (Please, next time provide a reproducible example)

So I will play with the `width` value in `style` fomr `DTOutput`:

```
ui.R ...  fluidRow(
            column(
                    width = 12,
                    box(width = NULL, status = "info", solidHeader = T, title = "Earnings Scanner",

                     DTOutput("tab"),style = "height:700px; width:700px; overflow-y: scroll;overflow-x: scroll;font-size:70%;"
                    )
                  )
                )



server.R ... output$tab = renderDT(
      datatable(
      frame.ea, filter = 'top', options = list(
        pageLength = 10, autoWidth = TRUE), class = 'cell-border stripe', rownames = F)
    )
```